# How does python load global variables?

Tags: python, function, variables, loading, global

[Couldn't find exactly what I wanted. Apologies if this is a duplicate question.]

In this code:

```
import heavy_function

_data = heavy_function()

def foo():
    print _data

def bar():
    print 'Call no 1'
    foo()
    print 'Call no 2'
    foo()

bar()
```

If I am calling

> bar()

as it is shown in the code, or if I call it from other module by importing it, does the

> _data

get loaded each time the function calls it? or does it get loaded once and be stored for further use?

Comment: Once the statement `_data = heavy_function()` is executed the return value is stored in the variable and hence every time you use the variable the stored value is displayed

Comment: `_data` is a name that points to the return value of the function, you assign it once so the function is called once

Comment: Thank you people. That is what I intuitively expected, wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you load this module your `heavy_function()` gets loaded and store it's value into `_data` and this `_data` gets stored in `globals()`. And then it doesn't matter how many time you use that same object gets passed over.

For your understanding here I'm simultaing the function value just by giving a list `[1, 2, 3]`, here I'm checking the object identity by comparing `foo()` return value with `_data` and `refcount` to show that it not getting referenced more than once.

```
#import heavy_function
import sys
_data = [1, 2, 3] # heavy_function()

def foo():
    print _data

def bar():
    print 'Call no 1'
    value1 = foo()
    print sys.getrefcount(_data)
    print 'Call no 2'
    value2 = foo()
    print sys.getrefcount(_data)
    print 'call no 3'
    value3 = foo()
    print sys.getrefcount(_data)

    print 'Check referenced values..'
    print value1 is value2 

bar()
```

Output:

```
Call no 1
[1, 2, 3]
2
Call no 2
[1, 2, 3]
2
call no 3
[1, 2, 3]
2
Check referenced values..
True
```

Here if you see even after the third call the same object is getting returned from `foo` and this `print value1 is value2` one helps you to identify that.

Comment: My best gratitudes to you, @gsb-eng. I didn't know the getrefcount() function. This is cool!

Comment: I didn't know how mark as accepted. I thought I don't have enough reputation to do anything :) You answer IS the best!

Answer (score 0):

It's loaded once, then the returned value is referenced twice

Answer (score 0):

_data will be assigned the return value of heavy_function() only once (when the module is first imported or run). After that it will simply be accessed.

You should be careful not to try to assign it inside a function though without specifying first that it is a global by using the global keyword.

Comment: Suggesting `global` is a bad idea.